# Two conditional checks inside a Panda data frame access

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The command below works fine

```
idx = np.asarray(df.loc[df['lat1'] != '.'].ix[:,0].index)
```

but I'm trying to do something like this (with 2 conditions):

```
idx = np.asarray(df.loc[df['lat1'] != '.' and df['state'] == df['state'][0]].ix[:,0].index)
```

This throws the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-274-c07cda0be195>", line 1, in <module>
    idx = np.asarray(df.loc[df['lat1'] != '.' and df['state'] == df['state'][0]].ix[:,0].index)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1573, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I've looked it up but not able to find a suitable tweak for this case. Any leads would be appreciated.

[EDIT]: Based on the suggestion below, when I try this:

```
df[(df['lat1']!='.') & (df['state']== df['state'][0])]
```

I get

```
        lat1    long1          ...          state                county
5    34  11          ...             AK             Anchorage
7    1 -3          ...             AK             Anchorage
14   1 -5          ...             AK             Anchorage
30   7 -3          ...             AK             Anchorage
44   1 -4          ...             AK             Anchorage
47   1 -3          ...             AK             Anchorage
75   1 -4          ...             AK                Juneau
82    5 -1          ...             AK       Kenai Peninsula
102  4 -1          ...             AK  Fairbanks North Star
106  4 -1          ...             AK     Matanuska Susitna
137  3 -3          ...             AK     Matanuska Susitna

[11 rows x 5 columns]
```

How do I extract only the first column containing the indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this question has already been asked somewhere... But with pandas you can look at two conditions like this.

```
df[(df['lat1']!='.') & (df['state']== df['state'][0])]
```

You have to do bitwise operations

Comment: If you actually run it on a dataset, you'd find it gives an error like this:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: If you post your dataset then it would be easier to understand. But you can probably just fill nas. df = df.fillna('')

Comment: Please see EDIT above.

Comment: I don't understand your question. With the resulting dataframe you only want the first column containing indices? What does that mean? Also if my answer has helped you please upvote.